# How to check which SMB Version is enabled on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell

I am using Windows Server 2008 R2. I want to know which version of SMB is enabled on my server.

I used the following command in PowerShell to know the smb versions installed: `sc.exe qc lanmanworkstation`

In its output, the DEPENDENCIES shows two versions of SMB : `MRxSmb10` and `MRxSmb20`.

Now the confusion is out of 2 versions installed, which SMB version is enabled on my server? As windows server 2008 R2 does not support `get-smbconnection` command, I am unable to determine the specific version.

I also checked the registry path `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters` and there is no entry about SMB version.

Can anyone please tell me how to determine which SMB version is enabled on server if SMB versions are more than one?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't see `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters` containing key for `SMB1` with `REG_DWORD: 0` for *disabled*, then it is enabled, which adds up with the other method that indicated the `lanmanworkstation` having dependency for both `MRxSmb10` and `RxSmb20`.

As described in [How to detect, enable and disable SMBv1, SMBv2, and SMBv3](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2696547/how-to-detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-smbv2-and-smbv3-in-windows-and) section for Windows Server 2008 R2, you can disable SMBv1 with

```
sc.exe config lanmanworkstation depend= bowser/mrxsmb20/nsi
sc.exe config mrxsmb10 start= disabled
```

After that, `sc.exe query lanmanworkstation` should only show `MRxSmb20`.

Answer (score 0):

`echo  Verification de l'etat des protocoles SMB : echo  --------------------------------------- echo. for %%V in (1 2) do ( for /F %%L in ('sc qc lanmanworkstation ^| find "mrxsmb%%V0"') do ( echo  - Le gestionnaire reseau depend du protocole SMB V%%V for /F %%S in ('sc query mrxsmb%%V0 ^| find /C "RUNNING"') do ( IF %%S EQU 1 ( echo    OK, le service SMB V%%V est en cour d'execution, poursuite de l'execution du script ) else ( echo. echo    ******************************************************************************************************** echo    SMB V%%V n'est pas en cours d'execution, arret du script echo    Dans une console administrateur, taper les commandes ci-dessous puis redÃ©marrer le poste si nÃ©cessaire : echo. echo    C:^> sc qc lanmanworkstation ^(pour visualiser les dependances, mrxsmb10 = SMB V1, mrxsmb20 = SMB V2^) echo    C:^> sc config lanmanworkstation depend= bowser/mrxsmb20/nsi ^(Pour exclure la dependance du protocole SMB V1^) echo    C:^> sc config mrxsmb10 start= disabled ^(Pour dÃ©sactiver SMB V1^) echo    C:^> sc config mrxsmb20 start= auto ^(Pour lancer automatiquement SMB V2^) echo    C:^> net stop workstation /YES ^(Pour redÃ©marrer le service^) echo    C:^> net start workstation echo    ******************************************************************************************************** goto END_SCRIPT ) ) ) )`